# TestNG Listener equivalent for @BeforeClass, with access to context

Tags: java, spring, testng

I've spent several days looking for a way to move one of my `@BeforeClass` methods to listener class I can reference in xml where I define content os test suite.

Problem I'm facing is that I'm using Spring for DI, and in `@BeforeClass` method I add some attributes to testng context, so I can use them in other places (other listeners).

I tried using `onStart(final ITestContext context)` from `ITestListener`. But that method seems to be invoked before spring manages to create beans, and I cannot perform my operations, because all my beans are nulls.

I tried using `onBeforeClass(ITestClass testClass)` from `IClassListener`. But that method only provides `ITestClass`, which does not give me access to context, so I can't set my attributes.

Now I'm experimenting with `onConfigurationSuccess(final ITestResult itr)` from `IConfigurationListener`, but that requires using if statement to run my code only if configuration method name is equal to `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance`.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

[EDIT] code sample

```java
@Component
public class CleanupHelper {

  private static SomeBean someBean;

  @Autowired
  public CleanupHelper(SomeBean someBean){
    CleanupHelper.someBean = someBean;
  }

  public static Object getSomething(){
    return someBean.getSomething();
  }
}
```

```java
public class ExcludedGroupsListener implements IConfigurationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSuccess(final ITestResult itr) {
        if (itr.getName().contains("springTestContextPrepareTestInstance")) {
            var something = CleanupHelper.getSomething();
            if (something != null && someOtherCondition) {

                itr.setAttribute("someObject", something);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class SomeTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @Test
  public void someTest(){
    // doSomething
  }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.some",
        excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.some.else..*"))
public class TestConfig {
}
```

Above code works... unfortunately `onConfigurationSuccess` method is invoked after each configuration method.

Comment: Exactly what are you doing in your BeforeClass that you wanna move to the Listener? I'm thinking maybe an AnnoatationTransformer can help you there since it runs before runtime, but not sure without an example of what you are doing.

Comment: I used to have one base class that was extended by all test classes. BeforeClass method was allowing me to handle custom way of working with excluding certain groups of test. I removed base class and moved majority of shared methods to spring managed singletons and testng listeners. Unfortunately to handle this one method I need to access testng test context, but wasn’t able to find method that would be invoked after spring initialization, but before first test in given class... I’ll add code samples later today.

Comment: @klubi I have same problem too, did you found any solutions?

Comment: @mechanikos unfortunately I did not :/ I’m stuck with workaround described above

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Annotation Transformers](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers).

You can add it in your testng.xml like any other listener.

And in there you can do things like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class TestAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {

        if (testMethod.getName().equals("MyTest1"))
            annotation.setGroups( new String[] {"GroupA" });

        if(ignoreTestDependencies)
            annotation.setIgnoreMissingDependencies(true);

    }

}
```

Just an example, but you have many things there to play with.

Just bear in mind that, as I stated in the comments, this runs **before** runtime, so you won't be able to change things on the go like you would do with a normal listener.

Comment: Unfortunately this is invoked to early. Spring beans are not constructed yet.

Comment: hmm true. I wonder if you run testng programmatically instead of from the xml. I don't really have much time today to try this, but you could run your suite by other means, set a new TestNG(), set to it classes that you want to run and the Listeners (including the transformer). and then run it. But I'm just thinking from the top of my head there. It might not solve your problem. Hope you find a solution to it. Post it here if you do, I'm intrigued now.

Comment: I added code sample. Currently I run those tests from Jenkins, which invokes gradle task that runs given xml suite file. Switching to something else is an option... but won't be as elegant and simple as current setup.